# W32TM /register fails - The specified service has been marked for deletion (0x80070430)

Tags: windows-10, services, clock

During an unsuccessful attempt to sync my clock, I have run the command `w32tm /unregister`.

When I run `w32tm /register` I get the error: `The following error occurred: The specified service has been marked for deletion. (0x80070430)`.

How can I register the service again?

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer?

Answer (score 5):

You have to stop Windows Time Service when registering it:

1) `w32tm /unregister`

2) Hit Win+R and type services.msc

3) Find 'Windows Time' service and stop it

4) `w32tm /register`

5) Start Windows Time Service again.